# Find groups in data by relative difference between records

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have some rows that are sorted by price:

```
| id | price |
|----|-------|
|  1 |  2.00 |
|  2 |  2.10 |
|  3 |  2.11 |
|  4 |  2.50 |
|  5 |  2.99 |
|  6 |  3.02 |
|  7 |  9.01 |
|  8 |  9.10 |
|  9 |  9.11 |
| 10 | 13.01 |
| 11 | 13.51 |
| 12 | 14.10 |
```

I need to group them in "price groups". An item belongs to a different group when *difference* in price between it and the previous item is greater than some fixed value, say `1.50`.

So the expected result is something like this:

```
| MIN(price) | MAX(price) | 
|------------|------------|
|       2.00 |       3.02 |
|       9.01 |       9.11 |
|      13.01 |      14.10 |
```

I'm not even sure how to call this type of grouping. Group by "rolling difference"? Not exactly...

Can this be done in SQL (or in Postgres in particular)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results are consistent with looking at the previous value and saying a group starts when the difference is greater than 1.5.  You can do this with `lag()`, a cumulative sum, and aggregation:

```
select min(price), max(price)
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where prev_price is null or prev_price < price - 1.5) over (order by price) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(price) over (order by price) as prev_price
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gordon Linoff for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60045623/236195), it is exactly what I was after!

I ended up using this query here simply because I understand it better. I guess it is more noobish, but so am I.

Both queries sort a table of 1M rows into 34 groups in about a second. This query is a bit more performant on 11M rows, sorting them into 380 groups in 15 seconds, vs 23 seconds in Gordon's answer.

```sql
SELECT results.group_i, MIN(results.price), MAX(results.price), AVG(results.price)
FROM (
         SELECT *,
                SUM(new_group) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS group_i
         FROM (
                  SELECT annotated.*,
                         CASE
                             WHEN prev_price IS NULL OR price - prev_price > 1.5 THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                         END AS new_group
                  FROM (
                           SELECT *,
                                  LAG(price) OVER (ORDER BY price) AS prev_price
                           FROM prices
                       ) AS annotated
              ) AS grouppable
) AS results
GROUP BY results.group_i
ORDER BY results.group_i;
```